# Insert a NEW Row using a Single Value from LAST row with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert

Please refer to the screen captures below.

[image: Table Diagram]

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 that does the following:

1. Sets the "**Complete**" BIT in the LAST record (e.g. row #1062) to **TRUE**
2. Takes a the "**DateTo**" value from the LAST record (highlighted in yellow) and INSERTS it into the  "**DateFrom**" column in a NEW row.

That should be all that is required, as the other columns (BatchID, DateTo, Complete) are automatically populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two statement. First update the latest row, then insert the new one:

```
with cte as (select top (1) complete from billing_batch order by dateto desc)
update cte set complete = 1;

insert into billing_batch (datefrom)
select max(dateto) 
from billing_batch;
```

Comment: Trying to use your answer, @GMB 

The second step works PERFECTLY!

However, on the first step, I am getting an error

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'."

Comment: I just realized @GMB that I also needed to add 1 day to the "datefrom" in the new row, in order for the 7 day billing period to work properly

Comment: @CapnElectric: `dateadd(day, 1, max(dateto))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set complete = 1
    from (select top (1) t.*
          from t
          order by datefrom desc
         ) t;
```

And then:

```
insert into t (datefrom, complete)
    select top (1) dateto, 0
    from t
    order by datefrom desc;
```

Comment: Is `t` an alias or a table?

Comment: Should an update and an insert like this be wrapped in a transaction?